# Vue components usage

Tags: vue.js

I have simple vue component:

```
<vselect></vselect>
<vselect></vselect>    
<vselect></vselect>
<template id="tem_vselect">
    <span>Selected: {{ selected }}</span>
</template>

<script>
    Vue.component('vselect', {
        template: '#tem_vselect'
    });
</script>
```

And few questions:

1. How can i pass different 'selected' values for each instance of the
   component (i'm aware that 'props' or 'data' is missing but don't
   know which one is the right one)
2. How can i nest those select components in another component that will serve 'selected' values (parent data model) for each component (how to pass those value form
   parent component)?
3. How can i respond when any of the values in parent component model changes?

Comment: `data` is the component's internal state, `props` is the way to receive data.

Comment: but how to make new instance of component with custom data?

Comment: I recommend you watch [Laracast's tutorial on Vue 2](https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step). You're asking the basics that you'll learn in most any tutorial.

Comment: I have studied vue documentation but when it comes to usage of this knowledge i'm lost. I'll check that tutorial.thx.